# How to get the specific number of lines in a file using python programming?

Tags: python, file

This is my code for getting 20 lines every time but f1.tell() gives last position of the file. So i cannot get 20 lines for the next time.
Can anyone help me to do this? please

```
f1=open("sample.txt","r")
last_pos=0
while true:
    f1.seek(last_pos)
    for line,i in enumerate(f1.readlines()):
        if line == 20:
            last_pos=f1.tell()
            break
        else:
            print i
sample.txt file contains below data
1
2
3
4
.
.
.
.
40
I want Output like
1
2
3
4
.
.
.
20
20
21
22
23
24
25
.
.
.
.
39
39
40
```

Comment: You know that `f.tell()` returns the position of the file pointer in the file - it's not got anything to do with the number of lines? Are you trying to count the number of lines (as per your title suggests) in a file or do something else?

Comment: Yes actually it should return the current position of a file but it returns the last position. I want to print the data line by line in a file  but at a time  i want to print 20 lines only and next time i don't want to repeat those lines i want to print next 20 lines . So for that operation I am using f1.seek() to go to that particular position

Comment: So - are you trying to read over the file in chunks of 20 lines each?

Comment: ha yes I am trying to print 20 lines at a time

Comment: You're already loading the entire file into memory in your code so there shouldn't be a reason to want to keep file positions. You can just assign `lines = f1.readlines()` and then slice `lines` if your file is a "reasonable" size...

Comment: no @JonClements my file  might be having  lacks of lines so i think slicing is not the correct way to do it

Comment: Well - if your program didn't blow up when you tried the above - then your file clearly fits into memory...

Comment: Actually I have tried that one but  I want to try with some better options than slicing

Comment: If by better you mean more complicated, convoluted and by the looks of it unnecessary, then okay :p

Comment: Not like that  but if we use slicing and f.readlines() method the entire file should be in memory and every time it takes the total file and slices that right ? may be It will take more time and more memory

Comment: As I said previously - load the data once and keep it in a list somewhere... then slice that list whenever you need chunks..

Comment: If my file contains crores of line then how can i store those lines in a list it will be surely time taking process @JonClements

Comment: I take it that *crores* is tens of millions? Are you running the program once and wanting to read chunks of twenty, or reading it more than once and be able to skip N blocks per run?/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `readlines` reads all the file: you reach the end, hence what you are experiencing.

Using a loop with `readline` works, though, and gives you the position of the end of the 20th line (well, rather the start of the 21st)

Code (I removed the infinite loop BTW):

```
f1=open("sample.txt","r")
last_pos=0
line=0
while True:
    l=f1.readline()
    if l=="":
        break
    line+=1
    if line == 20:
        last_pos=f1.tell()
        print(last_pos)
        break
f1.close()
```

You could iterate with `for i,l in enumerate(f1):` but iterators & ftell are not compatible (you get: `OSError: telling position disabled by next() call`).

Then, to seek to a given position, just `f1.seek(last_pos)`

EDIT: if you need to print the line twice eveny 20 lines, you actually don't even need `seek`, just print the last line when you count 20 lines.

BUT if you really want to do that this way, here's the way:

```
f1=open("sample.txt","r")
line=0
rew=False

while True:
    start_line_pos=f1.tell()
    l=f1.readline()
    if l=="":
        break
    print(l.strip())
    line+=1
    if rew:
        rew = False   # avoid re-printing the 20th line again and again
    elif line % 20 == 0:
        f1.seek(start_line_pos)
        rew = True
        line-=1   # pre-correct line counter
f1.close()
```

You notice a bit of logic to avoid getting stuck on line 20. It works fine: when reaching line 20, 40, ... it seeks back to the previously stored file position and reads 1 line again. The `rew` flag prevents to do that more than once.

Comment: Thank u so much but How can I print those lines .First  time it is ok but second time how can we go to that particular position

Comment: I have tried this but it is not coming . It  only prints the first 20 lines and return the last position of a file

Comment: I think you're running your old program: my snippet doesn't print anything but the last position. added the fseek call in the end, you got that right.

Comment: hey Jean-Franscois Fabre i want to access the previous line after tell the position. That means after printing 20 i want to start printing from 20 on wards so how to do it? can u tell me please?

Comment: @surya not sure I understand. Can you rephrase?

Comment: yes  actually what your code will do is printing 20 lines and after that start from the 21st line. but i want to print 1-20 lines and after that 20-39 lines like that

Comment: not offset actually i want to print that 20 th line again as a starting line of the next 20 lines group

Comment: for example 20 is the data of 20th line

Comment: I want to print 1-20, again i want to print 20-39 and 39-48 like that

Comment: It is not working @Jean-Francois Fabre. after printing 20 lines again it is printing from the first line can u check it once

Comment: I think you have to provide an input file and expected input (please edit your question!). I really don't get what you want.

Comment: hey @Jean-Francois Fabre i have clearly edited my question please check once

Comment: Ok, now this is clear. This is also a much simpler problem. See my edit.

Comment: not like that @Jean-Francois Fabre i want to do it by  using file pointers only  i have already done this by using the code like your code

Comment: @surya finally took the time to implement it without buffers, only using `seek` and `tell` and some flags. Enjoy (and accept the answer if it answers your question)

Comment: hey Jean_Francois Fabre  thank you for your efforts on my code .It is working now but I got another doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Jean-François Fabre already explained that `readline` could read the whole file.

But anyway you should never mix line level input (`readline`) and byte level input (`tell`, `seek` or `read`). As the low level OS system calls can only read a byte count, `readline` actually reads a *buffer* and searches for a newline in it. But the file pointer given by `tell` is positionned at the end of the buffer and **not** at the end of the line.

There is no way to set the file pointer at the end of a line except by processing the file one char at a time and manually detecting the end of line.

Comment: sounds reasonable. But readline+ftell worked. The position given is the position of the 21st line as predicted. So is this luck? I'm running windows/python 3.5.